# Tkinter/ttk binding scroll wheel event to a menubutton or menu

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I have a menu with 50+ options for the user to select from. When the user clicks on the associated menubutton, the popup menu appears and the list extends to the edges of the screen. Not all of the options fit into this view. There are arrows at the top and bottom to click through the list, but it would be a lot nicer to be able to use the scroll wheel. I have tried to bind the scroll wheel event using `self.menu.bind('<MouseWheel>',self.onMouseWheel)`
and `self.root.bind_all('<MouseWheel>',self.onMouseWheel)` and neither works. What surprises me about the latter is that I would think that the popup menu would be part of the root and therefore impacted by the bindall command, but I get no response back when I scroll over the popup.

I am using ttk along with TKinter for aesthetics. However, the program is for personal use. So, if it is complicating things I can get away from that. Also, I'm using Python 2.7. If there is a benefit to upgrading to 3.4, I've been looking for a reason to do that anyway.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What about making a Toplevel popup that contains a Listbox or another alternative method?

Comment: Thanks, that's a possibility if all else fails. I'm curious though about what is preventing this. There are clearly actions as a result of events on the menu. For instance, when I click on an item in the menu an index is saved and and the menu closes. This should be a result of `<ButtonPress>` or `<Button-1>` event, yet I can't write custom commands for those actions. And I know events can be bound to the menu because the virtual event `<<MenuSelect>>` works.